# My For loop isn't exiting and I don't know why

Tags: arduino, avr, c, sd, c++

I'm programming an ATMEGA328p on a breadboard and using an arduino board to do the USB to Serial conversion.  Part of some code I'm writing involves a for loop that is being used to take the 8 bit output from the SPI MOSI line (connected to an SD card) and stick it into a 64 bit binary number so I can output it to the serial monitor.  I've been testing it, and I'm getting an infinite loop and I don't know what is wrong.  The code is posted below.  Don't worry about the USART code, it works.  The test case (the array purple[5]) is being used to find out why the for loop is infinite.

Also, if you know an easier way to output the 40 bit code that an SD card outputs after using the commands SEND_IF_COND and SD_SEND_OP_COND that would be helpful as well.

```
#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

void Init_USART(void);
void newLine(void);
void transmitByte(uint8_t my_byte);
void printNumber(uint8_t n);
void print64BitNumber(uint64_t bits);
void printBinaryByte(uint8_t byte);
void printString(const char myString[]);

int main(void){
    Init_USART();
    uint8_t purple[5];
    purple[0] = 0b11110111;
    purple[1] = 0b00010000;
    purple[2] = 0b11111111;
    purple[3] = 0b00110000;
    purple[4] = 0b11111111;
    uint8_t counter = 0;
    uint64_t push_bit = 1;
    uint64_t error_codes = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for (int loop_bit=7; ((loop_bit < 8)||(loop_bit < 254)); loop_bit--){
            push_bit = 1;
            printNumber(loop_bit);
            print64BitNumber(error_codes);
            newLine();
            printNumber(counter);
            newLine();
            if(bit_is_set(purple[i],loop_bit)){
                error_codes |= (push_bit << (loop_bit+(i*8)));
            }
            else{
                error_codes &= ~(push_bit <<(loop_bit+(i*8)));
            }
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//USART Functions///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Init_USART(void)
{
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0); //Enables the USART transmitter and receiver
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<USBS0); //tells it to send 8bit characters (setting both USCZ01 and UCSZ00 to one)
    //now it has 2 stop bits.

    UBRR0H = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8); //loads the upper 8 bits into the high byte of the UBRR register
    UBRR0L = BAUD_PRESCALE; //loads the lower 8 bits
}

void printBinaryByte(uint8_t byte){
    uint8_t bit = 0;
    //This code is really efficient.  Instead of
    //using large ints to loop, it uses small uint8_t's.
    for (bit=7; bit<255; bit--){
        if(bit_is_set(byte,bit)){
            transmitByte('1');
        }
        else{
            transmitByte('0');
        }
    }
}
//uint8_t is used for 8bit chars
void transmitByte(uint8_t my_byte){
    do{}while(bit_is_clear(UCSR0A, UDRE0));
    //UDR0 is the transmit register.
    UDR0 = my_byte;
}
void newLine(void){
    printString("\r\n");
}
void printString(const char myString[]){
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while(myString[i]){
        while ((UCSR0A &(1<<UDRE0)) == 0){}//do nothing until transmission flag is set
        UDR0 = myString[i]; // stick Chars in the register.  They gets sent.
        i++;
    }
}
//Prints 64 bit number.
void print64BitNumber(uint64_t bits){
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 56);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 48);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 40);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 32);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 24);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 16);
    printBinaryByte(bits >> 8);
    printBinaryByte(bits);
}


void printNumber(uint8_t n){//This function Prints a number to the serial monitor
    //Algorithm to convert 8 bit binary to 3 digit decimal.
    //N=16(n1)+1(n0)
    //N=n1(1*10+6*1)+n0(1*1)
    //N=10(n1)+1(6(n1)+1(n0))
    //Also: N = 100(d2)+10(d1)+1(d0)
    //Then make: a1 = n1 and a0 = (6(n1)+1(n0))
    //Then get rid of the carries since n0 can be from 0-15, etc.
    //c1 = a0/10 This is the number of 10's to carry over
    //d0 = a0%10 This is the decimal that's outputed.
    //c2 = (a1+c1)/10
    //d1 = (a1+c1)%10
    //d2 = c2
    uint8_t d2, d1, q;
    uint16_t d0;
    //0xF is 15
    //00010000 this is 16 (n)
    //d0 = 00010000 & 00001111, d0 = 00000000
    d0 = n & 0xF;
    //If you AND n then the bits in the original number show in d0,d1 and d2
    //d1 = (00010000 >> 4) same as 00000001, & 00001111, d1 = 00000001
    //this sees if there's anything in the second 4 bits
    d1 = (n>>4) & 0xF;
    d2 = (n>>8);
    //this sets d2 to 0.

    d0 = 6*(d2+d1)+d0;
    q = d0/10;
    d0 = d0%10;

    d1 = q + 5*d2 + d1;
    if (d1!=0){
        q = d1/10;
        d1 = d1%10;

        d2 = q+2*d2;
        if (d2!=0){
            transmitByte(d2 + '0');
            //remember to add '0' because its an ASCII char
        }
        transmitByte(d1 + '0');
    }
    transmitByte(d0 + '0');

}
```

Comment: There is a decent amount of code here. Can you give us a minimum working example? (ie: how much can you rip out and still make it loop forever?) It might even turn out that you can solve the problem yourself when you see the issue without another 100 lines of code around it.

Comment: This is the minimum working example.  The only code I'm concerned with here is the nested for loops in main.  I just posted the rest of the code in case someone had an arduino laying around and wanted to try it out for themselves with putty or a different terminal.

Comment: "This is the minimum working example. ... I just posted the rest of the code" - then it isn't a minimum working example.

Comment: This is not all of the code.  I just wanted to include the USART code so it's easy for someone to see the output as the code loops.

Comment: In one of your for loops you have a variable 'loop_bit' which is declared as an 'int', but you are subtracting 1 from it and then checking if it is < 254 (and pointlessly if it is < 8 which is implied by it being <254). That will take many many iterations (has to count down to -32768, then to 32767) before it exits.

Comment: Oh, wow.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.  It works now.  Put this as an answer and I'll give you a green check mark. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code you have the following suspect line:

```
for (int loop_bit=7; ((loop_bit < 8)||(loop_bit < 254)); loop_bit--){
    ...
}
```

The key problem with this is that as `loop_bit` is an 'int'. In avr-gcc this is a 16bit signed data type. You have a loop condition which is `loop_bit < 254` (and the redundant `loop_bit < 8`). As such if you keep subtracting 1, you have to count all the way down to -32768 and then one iteration further to have it wrap around to 32767 before the for loop will exit.

If you want to count down from 7 to 0 inclusive, you can do one of the following two things:

1. This is closest to what you currently have

   ```
   for (int loop_bit=7; loop_bit>=0; loop_bit--){
       ...
   }
   ```
2. This is more efficient on an 8-bit AVR

   ```
   for (int8_t loop_bit=7; loop_bit>=0; loop_bit--){ //assuming avr-gcc understands 'int8_t', if not you can do 'char'
       ...
   }
   ```

---

As a side note, and just my personal opinion, in another part of the code, you also have this for loop:

```
for(bit=7; bit<255; bit--){
    ...
}
```

This will work fine as bit is declared as a `uint8_t`, but it would be more readable to declare 'bit' as a signed `int8_t` type and use the following loop:

```
for(bit=7; bit>=0; bit--){
    ...
}
```

Using the signed type allows the number to go negative and cause the loop to exit. Functionally (and probably in assembly) the two loops are identical as I say, but personally I find the latter easier to follow.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `int8` as a standard integer type.  Is is specific to Arduino? I can't find it in their core source code...  I think you may mean `int8_t` which is defined in `stdint.h` and as the filename suggests is a *ST*an*D*ard *INT*eger typedef.

Comment: @Majenko you are correct, int8_t is what I was thinking of, I knew there was something else in it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I only questioned it because I have seen people use int8 and uint8 as their own custom typedefs. I wish people would standardize...  I have seen all combinations of s8, u8, si8, ui8, int8, uint8, etc used all over the place where using the standard int8_t and uint8_t would be more sensible...

Comment: @TomCarpenter - this is a bit pedantic, but `int_least8_t` is a better choice than `int8_t`. The latter does not exist on (admittedly rare) systems that don't have a native 8-bit type. The former will always work.